# Invalid table or object when doing query on temp table (Pervasive SQL)

Tags: sql, pervasive-sql

I have a SP that inserts records into a temp table, then selects the records and returns them.  The SQL is this.

I troubleshot it by removing the INSERT INTO statement, and minimizing the SQL.  The culprit is the SELECT * FROM #Worklist1.  No idea why this does not work.  I upgraded (just now) to latest version of Pervasive server ver 10 if that helps, but this issue was in 10.3 and its still there.  Must be missing something.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE "Connect_Workflow"(
     :StartDate DATETIME, :EndDate DATETIME)
     RETURNS(Patient varchar(100) , 
        AccessionNo varchar(25)  
        );
BEGIN
    CREATE TABLE #WorkFlow1
        (Patient varchar(100) null, 
        AccessionNo varchar(25) null 
    );  
    INSERT INTO #Workflow1(
      SELECT 
        rtrim(p.LastName),--+ '^' + rtrim(p.FirstName) + isnull('^' + rtrim(p.Initial), ''),
        v.VisitID   -- equiv to EncounterID
    FROM visit v
    join patient p on v.patientnumber = p.patientnumber
    WHERE v.VisitYY = '99'
    );

    SELECT * FROM #WorkFlow1;
    DROP TABLE #Workflow1;


END
```

Update:  After commenting out the SELECT * FROM #Worklist1; it still gives a invalid table error.  If I remove the INSERT INTO  and the SELECT * then finally the error is gone.  Must be error in referencing the table.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the DROP TABLE #Workflow1; from your query.
I believe it's dropping the table before the SP returns the data.

Comment: When I remove DROP TABLE, the SP fires once.  When I fire it again, it complains that the table already exists.  When I put a DROP TABLE right before the CREATE TABLE, it says 'No such table or object'.  Definitely something going on with creating/dropping the temp table.

Comment: Are you running it twice in the same connection or different connections?

Comment: I am running it from Pervasive Control Center.  I load a SQL document in another window and type exec ProcName(var1,var2).  BTW i am working with the DEMODATA table and getting the same exact issue.

Comment: I've been using ODBC Test. Let me try PCC.

Comment: I tested on V10 with the PCC and saw the same error.  I tried it in ODBC Test with v10 and did not see any errors.  I also tried it in PCC with v11 and did not see any errors.  Might be something specific to the v10 PCC.  I see you've got a solution though so it doesn't really matter at this point.

Answer (score 0):

Okay i figured it out.  Although the procedure should work fine, in fact Pervasive recommends something like this.  use SELECT INTO

```
CREATE PROCEDURE "Connect_Workflow"(
     :StartDate DATETIME, :EndDate DATETIME)
     RETURNS(Patient varchar(100) , 
        AccessionNo varchar(25)  
        );
BEGIN
    SELECT 
        rtrim(p.LastName),--+ '^' + rtrim(p.FirstName) + isnull('^' + rtrim(p.Initial), ''),
        v.VisitID   -- equiv to EncounterID
    FROM visit v
    INTO #Workflow1
    join patient p on v.patientnumber = p.patientnumber
    WHERE v.VisitYY = '99'
    );
    SELECT * FROM #WorkFlow1;
END
```